# Redirecting user on correct/incorrect login

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on this for sometime now and just can't figure out what am I doing wrong here.

### Scenario:

I am working on a PHP application where the user would enter his login credentials and on successful validation, he would be redirected to his home page. Codewise:

```
index.php -> login_handler.php -> user_home.php
```

But I just cannot redirect the user to the home page on successful login and to the login page on incorrect login. I have posted the relevant portion of code below.

[image]

### index.php:

```
<div id="LoginFormWrapper">
      <div class="login-block">
            <h3 align="left">
            <span style="font-family: 'Verdana'; color: white; font-weight: bold;font-size: 12px;margin-left: 10px;">
            <?php
                $queryString = http_build_query($_GET, '', '|');
                echo $queryString;
                if ($queryString == "status=Session+expired.Please+login%21") {
                    echo("Session expired.Please login!");
                }
                if ($queryString == "status=Login+Failed+%21") {
                    echo("Login failed !");
                }
                if ($queryString == "status=Registration+Succesful.") {
                    echo("Congrats ! Login to explore...");
                }
            ?>
            </span>
            </h3>
            <br/>
            <form name="UserLogin" action="login_handler.php" method="post" class="loginform">
                <p align="left"><label for="user_id">User Id :</label><input type="text" name="user_id" id="user_id"  align="right"/></p>
                <p align="left"><label for="password">Password :</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" align="right" /></p>
                <p align="left"><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login"/>
                <b>
                    <span style="font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', fantasy; color: white; font-size:14px;">Want to register ?</span>
                </b> 
                <a href="Registration.php">
                    <img id="signupbutton" src="images/signup-button.png" alt="signup" width="76" height="41" longdesc="signup-button.png" />
                </a>
              </p>
            </form> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

### login_handler.php:

```
<?php
        include ("DatabaseOperations.php");
        $user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        //echo $user_id;
        $status = validateLogin($user_id, $password);
        if (!$status) { // Redirect to Home Page with the error message printed above the login form.
            header('Location: index.php?status=Login Failed !');
        } else {
            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "cheque_management");
            $query = "select `user_id` from `user_master` where `user_id` = '$user_id' and `password` = '$password'";
            if ($result = $mysqli -> query($query)) {
                while ($row = $result -> fetch_row()) {
                    //echo $row[0];
                    $status = $row[0];
                }
                // Code to set the sessions....
                //First checks for an existing session ID number,
                //If it finds one, it sets up the $_SESSION array.If not, it starts a new session by creating a new session ID number.
                session_start();
                // creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                $_SESSION['session_id'] = session_id();
                // Binding the form inputted userid value with a session variable.
                $session_id = $_SESSION['session_id'];
                // Explicitly generating a unique session id for the current session.
                header('Location: user_home.php?status=' . $status . '&session_id=' . $session_id);
                // Assigning newly generated session id to a variable.
            }
            //mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        ?>
```

### DatabaseOperations.php:

```
<?php

function getConnectionLink() {
    echo "Inside getConnectionLink()"."<br/>"; 
    return mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password'); // Returns a MySQL link identifier if the connection is successful or FALSE on failure.
}

function getDB() {
    echo "Inside getDB()"."<br/>";  
    $link_host = getConnectionLink();
    $con_status = mysql_select_db('cheque_management', $link_host); // Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
    return $con_status;
}

function validateLogin($user_id, $password) {
    echo "Inside validateLogin()"."<br/>"; 
    $link_host = getConnectionLink();
    echo "$link_host = ".$link_host; // Doesn't print anything.
    $con_status = getDB();
    $sql = "select * from `user_master` where `user_id` = '$user_id' and `password` = '$password'";
    echo $sql; // Doesn't print anything.
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link_host);
    if (!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
        echo "Valid Login";// Invalid login
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        echo "Valid Login"; // Valid login.
        return TRUE;
    }
}
?>
```

### Edit:

The MySQL server is up and running and the query seems OK. `sandeep` and `123` , that is what is being entered on the login page.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please google "Bobby Tables" right away. Then you'll probably want to google "sql injection".

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with you db query. Avoid mysql extension that has been deprecated for modern php at all times. You may want to encrypt your passwords in production as well and sanitize the data a bit more.

Here's a prototype, you should run in with stubbed data until it returns correct results. After you can connect your dummy data with the form submission.

Updated to be a complete single page self-submitting script that will redirect to user_home.php on success. Just edit form action to match script filename.

```
    class MySql
    {
        private $sDbName      = 'play';
        private $sUsername    = 'root';
        private $sPassword    = '';
        private $sHost        = 'localhost';
        private $oConnection  = null;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->oConnection = new PDO( 
                'mysql:host=' 
                . $this->sHost 
                . ';dbname=' 
                . $this->sDbName, 
                $this->sUsername, 
                $this->sPassword 
                );
        }
        public function getDb()
        {
            return $this->oConnection;
        }

        public function bindVariables( &$oStmp, $aBinds )
        {
            foreach( $aBinds as $sVariable => $vValue )
            {
                // Ensure we have a colon prepended for PDO.
                if( substr( $sVariable, 0, 1 ) !== ':' )
                {
                    $sVariable = ':' . $sVariable;
                }
                $oStmp->bindValue( $sVariable, $vValue );
            }
        }
    }
    session_start();
    if( !empty( $_POST ) && !empty( $_POST[ 'username' ] ) && !empty( $_POST[ 'username' ] ) )
    {
        $oMySql = new MySql;
        $oDb = $oMySql->getDb();
        $sSql = "SELECT count( 1 ) FROM user_master where username = :username and password = :password";
        $aBinds[ 'username' ] = $_POST[ 'username' ];
        $aBinds[ 'password' ] = $_POST[ 'username' ];

        $oStmp = $oDb->prepare( $sSql );
        $oMySql->bindVariables( $oStmp, $aBinds );
        $oStmp->execute();
        $oResult = $oStmp->fetchall();
        if( !empty( $oResult ) )
        {
            // User record exists.
            $sSql = "SELECT username FROM user_master where username = :username and password = :password LIMIT 1";
            $oMySql->bindVariables( $oStmp, $aBinds );
            $oStmp->execute();
            $oUser = $oStmp->fetch();
            $_SESSION[ 'username' ] = $oUser[ 0 ];
            header( 'Location: user_home.php?status=good&session_id=' . $oUser[ 0 ] );
        }
        else
        {
            // User record does not exist.
            header( 'Location: index.php?status=Login Failed !' );
        }
        var_dump( $oResult );
    }
?>
<div id="LoginFormWrapper">
      <div class="login-block">
            <h3 align="left">
            <span style="font-family: 'Verdana'; color: white; font-weight: bold;font-size: 12px;margin-left: 10px;">
            <?php
                $queryString = http_build_query($_GET, '', '|');
                echo $queryString;
                if ($queryString == "status=Session+expired.Please+login%21") {
                    echo("Session expired.Please login!");
                }
                if ($queryString == "status=Login+Failed+%21") {
                    echo("Login failed !");
                }
                if ($queryString == "status=Registration+Succesful.") {
                    echo("Congrats ! Login to explore...");
                }
            ?>
            </span>
            </h3>
            <br/>
            <form name="UserLogin" action="66.php" method="POST" class="loginform">
                <p align="left"><label for="username">User Id :</label><input type="text" name="username" id="user_id"  align="right"/></p>
                <p align="left"><label for="password">Password :</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" align="right" /></p>
                <p align="left"><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login"/>
                <b>
                    <span style="font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', fantasy; color: white; font-size:14px;">Want to register ?</span>
                </b> 
                <a href="Registration.php">
                    <img id="signupbutton" src="images/signup-button.png" alt="signup" width="76" height="41" longdesc="signup-button.png" />
                </a>
              </p>
            </form> 
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, point noted. I will work on hashing my passwords and avoid mysql extension, but I need to fix this first. :) The query seems to be Ok, I have edited my question..pls. have a look.

Comment: Updated. Hope it helps buddy.

Answer (score 0):

> I think issue is in getConnectionLink() function

mysql_connect returns true or false Boolean value only.true on success or false on failure.
It's return resource id#25 do this inside function.

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
if(!$con) {die("could not  onnect ".mysql_error());}
return $con;
```

Where $con has true or false value.
Go to this link to know about deprecation,uses, return of function [MySQL CONNECT](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are calling `getConnectionLink()` in `validateLogin()` and again from `getDB()` function. The resources return by `getConnectionLink()` will be different in these two functions. You need to pass the same resource# which is returned by `getConnectionLink()` to `getDB()` function.

Kindly refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php to see an example of same.

Thanks 
Anurag Sethi